# How to get back sql table data?

Tags: sql-server

IDE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Mistakenly I have cleaned a table data using

```
delete from table tblBookData
```

and now it has cleaned that table, please tell me is there any way to get back that data?

If yes than please tell me the process, as I have studied there is a way to get back data if we have not closed the session.

Comment: Restore your backup

Comment: I don't have backup, Is there any way using rollback?

Comment: np. also check docs what rollback is.

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: Take a look at this. This might help you [HERE](http://raresql.com/2011/10/22/how-to-recover-deleted-data-from-sql-sever/)

Comment: Pro Tip: Never ever use a DELETE **WITHOUT a WHERE CLAUSE** - unless you know that everything is going to get deleted :-) ...

Answer (score 0):

Restore the DB into another DB , while restoring select "To a point in Time" and select "A specific date and time" and enter the date time before you deleted the record

Comment: How does taking a backup of an empty table help restoring it contents?

Comment: I think there's a language issue here -- what's meant is "take" as in "use", not "take" as in "create."

Comment: no need to take backup,you can restore the DB into another DB...but the time you specify should should be the time at which you believe there is data in the table...